# Can a Jar File be updated programmatically without rewriting the whole file?

Tags: java, jar

It is possible to update individual files in a JAR file using the `jar` command as follows:

```
jar uf TicTacToe.jar images/new.gif
```

Is there a way to do this programmatically?

I have to rewrite the entire jar file if I use `JarOutputStream`, so I was wondering if there was a similar "random access" way to do this.  Given that it can be done using the `jar` tool, I had expected there to be a similar way to do it programmatically.

Comment: I know you can call batch processes in java. You can try calling that command when you want to update the jar.

Comment: Look to [JarFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/regex/Pattern.html) API.

Comment: @agad JarFile is for reading only unfortunately :(

Comment: .jar is a archived format, just try to find package for zipping/unzipping package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to update just parts of the JAR file using [Zip File System Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) available in Java 7:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ZipFSPUser {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Throwable {
        Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>(); 
        env.put("create", "true");
        // locate file system by using the syntax 
        // defined in java.net.JarURLConnection
        URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:/codeSamples/zipfs/zipfstest.zip");

       try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)) {
            Path externalTxtFile = Paths.get("/codeSamples/zipfs/SomeTextFile.txt");
            Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath("/SomeTextFile.txt");          
            // copy a file into the zip file
            Files.copy( externalTxtFile,pathInZipfile, 
                    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING ); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, is the file compressed as specified by the ZIP algorithm, or is it just plain added to the archive?

Comment: It is compressed with the default compression level.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you use this opensource library you can modify it in this way as well.

https://truevfs.java.net

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    File entry = new TFile("c:/tru6413/server/lib/nxps.jar/dir/second.txt");
    Writer writer = new TFileWriter(entry);
    try {
        writer.write(" this is writing into a file inside an archive");         
    } finally {
        writer.close();
    }       
}
```