# Java .jar file not finding system file when it is there and following the correct path

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, jar

I am getting these file not found exceptions when running the .jar, but not when running my application in netbeans. Here are the error messages, with a current directory print at the top.

adam@Adam ~/Dropbox/linuxWorkspace/Netbeans/EveMarketCalculater/dist $ java -jar "EveMarketCalculater.jar"

Current sys dir: /home/adam/Dropbox/linuxWorkspace/Netbeans/EveMarketCalculater/dist

java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/adam/Dropbox/linuxWorkspace/Netbeans/EveMarketCalculater/dist/EveMarketCalculater.jar!/inputOutput/TypeID.csv (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:58)
    at inputOutput.csvParser.readFile(csvParser.java:54)
    at inputOutput.csvParser.(csvParser.java:24)
    at evemarketcalculater.EveMarketCalculater.main(EveMarketCalculater.java:39)

java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/adam/Dropbox/linuxWorkspace/Netbeans/EveMarketCalculater/dist/EveMarketCalculater.jar!/inputOutput/Regions.csv (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:58)
    at inputOutput.csvParser.readFile(csvParser.java:54)
    at inputOutput.csvParser.(csvParser.java:24)
    at evemarketcalculater.EveMarketCalculater.main(EveMarketCalculater.java:42)

java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/adam/Dropbox/linuxWorkspace/Netbeans/EveMarketCalculater/dist/EveMarketCalculater.jar!/inputOutput/SolarSystems.csv (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:58)
    at inputOutput.csvParser.readFile(csvParser.java:54)
    at inputOutput.csvParser.(csvParser.java:24)
    at evemarketcalculater.EveMarketCalculater.main(EveMarketCalculater.java:45)

java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/adam/Dropbox/linuxWorkspace/Netbeans/EveMarketCalculater/dist/EveMarketCalculater.jar!/inputOutput/MyOrders.csv (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:58)
    at inputOutput.csvParser.readFile(csvParser.java:96)
    at inputOutput.csvParser.(csvParser.java:29)
    at evemarketcalculater.EveMarketCalculater.main(EveMarketCalculater.java:48)

Here is some source code of how I am accessing these files:

```
    public final void readFile(String file, int index1, int index2)
{
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplit = ",";
    idList = new ArrayList();

    try
    {
       URL url = csvParser.class.getResource(file);

       br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(url.getPath()));

       while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
       {
           String[] item = line.split(cvsSplit);

           idList.add(item[index1].replace("\"",""));
           idList.add(item[index2].replace("\"",""));
       }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(br != null)
    {
        try
        {
            br.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


    public static void writeMyOrders()
{
    URL url = csvParser.class.getResource("MyOrders.csv");

    FileWriter w = null;
    csvWriter c = null;

    try
    {
        // Empty file cotents
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(url.getPath());
        writer.close();

        w = new FileWriter(url.getPath());

        c = new csvWriter();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < myOrders.size(); i++)
    {
        try
        {
            c.writeLine(w, myOrders.get(i));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if(w != null)
        try
        {
            w.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Any clue why this isn't working? It's obviously tracing the right file path, and the files exist inside of the .jar file at these paths. I'm running in a Linux command line if that matters.

Here is proof that the files exist.

[picture of .jar directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F96vB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following statement while creating `BufferedReader`:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(csvParser.class.getResourceAsStream(file)));
```

`Class.getResource()` returns you the `URL` while `Class.getResourceAsStream()` gives you `InputStream` from where you can read the file contents directly.

**Explanation**
From the error message, it is visible that your application is unable to find the file `file:/home/adam/Dropbox/linuxWorkspace/Netbeans/EveMarketCalculater/dist/EveMarketCalculater.jar!/inputOutput/TypeID.csv`. To verify that, you can try opening the mentioned file with any other application like `gedit` or `chrome` or `vi`. If you can open it, your application can also do that.

You got such a path from the `URL` returned from `getResource()`. When it is `getResourceAsStream()`, you are provided with an `InputStream` with the resource you are looking for.

You have the option to update the file in a jar file. Haven't tried by myself, but you may refer to [Can a Jar File be updated programmatically without rewriting the whole file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353423/can-a-jar-file-be-updated-programmatically-without-rewriting-the-whole-file)

Comment: This works. How would I do this for writing to these files?

Also if you could explain a little more why getting a resource as a stream works but getting it with reader doesn't I would appreciate it.

Comment: With regards to writing, specifically something that applies to my second method in the original post. I've gotten past the original errors and it now drops the same error once I reach there. The PrintWriter is used to clear the file contents and then the FileWriter is what I use to update the file contents

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(file)));
```