# JAVA: run jar file and recreate jar file

Tags: java, build, jar, executable-jar

I must run a java jar file from command line to execute a batch script. This script produce a file that I must include in a package of my jar.
The idea is to run jar file to execute the batch script and after, in some way, rebuild the jar including the file produced from batch script.
Is it possible?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you want to rebuild the jar file with command line tools or with Java?

Comment: ideally with java after run the batch script.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/32353423/318758

Comment: Works! Thanks!!